# Fuzzy finding directories is slow

Tags: fzf, fd

I have following bash script to find git repositories.

```bash
echo "$(fd -I -i -H -E '.local' -E '.cargo' -E '.password-store' -t d ^.git$ ~ -x 'echo' '{//}' | sk)"
```

`fd` pipes search results to `sk` (fzf rust alternative) as they are being found but selecting one item waits until `fd` to finish. So there is like a 2 second delay from me selecting the directory using `sk` to it actually being `echo`ed. I can see the same behavior with `fzf` too.

Is there a way to avoid the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours I came up with this. There are probably better solutions but this works too.

```bash
#!/bin/env bash

quick_exit ()
{
  read VAR
  if [ ! -z "${VAR}" ]; then
    echo $VAR
    PID=$$
    kill $PID 2&> /dev/null
  fi
}

fd -I -i -H \
  -E '.local' \
  -E '.cargo' \
  -E '.password-store' \
  -t d ^.git$ ~ \
  -x 'echo' '{//}' | sk | quick_exit
```